# How do I compare an NSNumber to a swift enumeration value?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying to do a simple comparison of a value received via an NSNotification, and an enumeration value. I have something that works, but I can't believe that this is the right way to be doing this. Basically the solution I ended up with was converting the NSNumber to an Int, and also getting the enum value's rawValue, wrapping it in an NSNumber and then getting the integerValue of that.

Everything else I tried resulted in compiler errors about not being able to convert between Uint 8 and Int or something similar.

```
    observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in

        println(AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.toRaw())

        if let reason = notification.userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey!] as? NSNumber  {
            if (reason.integerValue == NSNumber(unsignedLong:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.toRaw()).integerValue) {
                self.headphoneJackedIn = true;
            } else if (reason.integerValue == NSNumber(unsignedLong:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable.toRaw()).integerValue) {
                self.headphoneJackedIn = false;
            }
            self.updateHeadphoneJackLabel()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using `fromRaw` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
if reason.integerValue == Int(AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue) {
    // ...
}
```

*Remark:* The `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason` enumeration uses `UInt` as raw value type, so
one could expect that this works without an explicit conversion:

```
if reason.unsignedIntegerValue == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue {

}
```

However, as of Xcode 6 beta 4, `NSUInteger` is mapped to Swift's `Int` in OS X and iOS
system frameworks, which means that both `integerValue` and `unsignedIntegerValue` return an  `Int`,
and an explicit conversion is needed in any case.

Alternatively, you could create an enumeration value from the number (as already suggested by @ColinE
in a comment) and then use switch case:

```
if let r = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: UInt(reason.integerValue)) {
    switch r {
    case .NewDeviceAvailable:
        // ...
    case .OldDeviceUnavailable:
        // ...
    default:
        // ...
    }
} else {
    println ("Other reason")
}
```

For the same reason as above, an explicit `UInt` conversion is necessary here as well.

Comment: This makes sense, I'll try it. I think the part I was missing was how to convert from Int to UInt. I was trying to do things like 'as Uint' and nothing was working.

Comment: Since Xcode 6.1 you have to use `Enum(rawValue: value)` instead of `Enum.fromRaw(value)`. See here: [Initializing from a Raw Value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_226)

Comment: @Cornelius: You are completely right. I have fixed the answer, thanks for the feedback!